# R. Apply custom-made function after group_by using dplyr

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have a data frame A. I created several sub data frames from A (A1,A2,A3, etc) using a for loop, grouping according to the 22 levels of column CHR. Now I want to apply a custom made function "diff_set" to each of these 22 sub data frames, which removes some unwanted observations. Then I want to rbind the output into a single data frame B and perform more operations on all observations in B. For this, I considered a general strategy that mixes for loops (to remove unwanted observations = rows) and then use dplyr for the rest of operations.

So first I created a list of data frames:

```
df_list = list(A1,A2,A3,...,A22)
```

The function "diff_set" is:

```
diff_set <- function(x, gap) {
  ind <- c(F, diff(x) > gap)
  if(sum(ind) == 0) return(x)
  x[-unique(c(which(ind), which(ind)-1))]
}
```

Then I applied "diff_set" to the list of data frames:

```
B = lapply(A, function(i) diff_set(i$POSITION, 200000))
```

However, this does not seem to work. I must be doing some silly mistake.

My general question is whether, for problems like this one, is it more convenient to use for-loops, packages like dplyr, or both combined together. I really would like to avoid generating output objects in each for loop that one needs to convert into a list as input for subsequent operations. dplyr pipes output objects directly with the %>% operator. For instance, I can easily generate the 22 sub data frames using group_by:

```
B = A %>% group_by(CHR)
```

but then I am unable to run diff_set using dlpyr. I tried using dplyr::do but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
B = A %>% group_by(CHR) %>% 
    do(out=data.frame(diff_set(.$POSITION, 200000))) %>% # Here I apply do
    group_by(regions=cut(i$POSITION, breaks=seq(0,250000000, by=100000) # example of subsequent operation

# i represents each 22 resulting sub data frames (i = 1-22)
```

I am very confused about how to proceed. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For working with 'sub data frames' look at tidyr's nest(), combined with functional tools from purrr.

Comment: Thank you @justincress, it would be really helpful if you could illustrate me with an example